# Php Mysql login beginner Admin/ User

Tags: php, mysql

Am working in a project at school, i want to sign in as a guest and it will direct me to a specific page everiting run smootly. But, i cant figure it out how i can sign in as the admin and make my code recognized it so it will bring me to the admin page....

```
    if (isset($_POST['login'])){

    $courriel_membre =  $_POST['courriel_membre'];
    $password = $_POST['password_membre'];

    // ensure that form fields are filled properly
    if (empty($courriel_membre)){

        array_push($errors,"Nom de utilisateur requit"); // Ajou de erreur 
dans le tableau erreur

    }
    if (empty($password)){

        array_push($errors,"Mot de passe requit"); // Ajou de erreur dans le 
tableau erreur  
    }

    if(count($errors) == 0 ){
        $password = md5($password); // decencrypt passwor avant de conmparer 
au databas
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM membres 
    WHERE courriel_membre = '$courriel_membre' 
    AND password_membre = '$password'";
       $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){

        $_SESSION['courriel_membre'] = $courriel_membre;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Vous etes maintenant connecte";
        header('location: affichageAccueil.php');// renvoit dans la page 
index.php*/
        }else{
            array_push($errors, "Mauvais nom de utilisateur ou mot de 
passe!");
            header('location: affichageFormConnexion.php');
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: you want different users to login on same page?

Comment: this is so unsafe. You're not taking this to the Internet are you? it's a heck of a fight out there and you stand at losing.

Comment: no, no internet its really a beginner project my next semester will be to learn the security behind it. And no only 1 user to log in either the user that it will bring to the home page and the admin will bring me to the admin page.

Comment: What database table holds the info about admin users?

Comment: Its you that have to declare who is admin based on some indaction somewhere.

Comment: Or which table field defines a user as admin?

Comment: My answer is totaly valid idk why it got downvoted.

Comment: I think you are downvoted becuse this is very bad practice but i beleive everyone has to start somewhere!

Comment: yes am starting its my second course on php  i have a table assign as members witch i assign a role example 1 = admin and 2 = users P.S Thanks for the quick answers really appreciated

Comment: What's the filename of your admin page? And what's the table field for user roles?

Answer (score -1):

You should have a user type field in the database. The administrator could asign a value to it like user, admin, moderator. When a user log in you check credentials and the type of user. If it's a user you declare a user session variable, If it's an admin you declare an admin session var.

Just like you verify if a user session exist you verify if an admin session exist.